# How can I pass a list of objects from Controller to View, where data is retrieved from database using Linq in ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass a list of Objects from controller to View ,where the attributes of the objects are retrieved from database using LINQ. The MODEL Code is given below:

```
public class Department
    {

        [Key]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Department Name")]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller Code is :

```
public ActionResult ShowDepartments()
        {

          var departmentList = db.Deapartment.Select(x => new
            {
                x.DepartmentId,
                x.DepartmentName

            }).ToList();


            return View(departmentList);
        }
```

And the View Code is:

```
@model List<PractiseMVC11_17_2017.Models.Department>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowDepartments";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Show Departments</h2>



        <div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var department in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @department.DepartmentId
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @department.DepartmentName

                    </td>

                </tr>

            }

        </tbody>



    </table>


</div>


}
```

But when I run the project, it shows the following exception:

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PractiseMVC11_17_2017.Models.Department]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shyju answer works because the object you are passing to the View happens to be the same as the database object.  This will not always be the case (it's, in fact, better if it is not).

The correct way to handle this is to create a named object:

```
      var departmentList = db.Deapartment.Select(x => new Department
        {
            x.DepartmentId,
            x.DepartmentName

        }).ToList();
```

(I'd go with the LINQ syntax, but the lambda syntax works just as well)

```
      var departmentList = 
                  (from x in db.Deapartment
                   select new Department
                  {
                       x.DepartmentId,
                       x.DepartmentName
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `Department` class objects. But in your action method, you are creating a list of new anonymous objects with this code

```
db.Deapartment.Select(x => new
                             {
                                x.DepartmentId,
                                x.DepartmentName

                     })
```

Here you are creating  an anonymous  object with the `DepartmentId` and `DepartmentName` property, for each item in the `db.Deapartment` collection. You are passing the result of the above code, which is a list of anonymous objects to the view. Your view now getting a different type than it is strongly typed to , hence you are getting the exception.

So simply pass `ToList()` on `db.Deapartment` and pass that to the view.

```
public ActionResult ShowDepartments()
{
    var departmentList = db.Deapartment.ToList();
    return View(departmentList);
}
```

Here `departmentList` variable will be a collection of `Deapartment` objects.